# Limit Variable Value - best way

Tags: java

quick question,

what is the best and most effective way to limit a variable in range of, say, 534 and -840.

Do I use Math.max methods here too?

Comment: What do you mean by "limit a variable"?

Comment: I think he means to clamp the value, given what he wants to use in order to do it...

Comment: I don't want the value of the variable to be greater than 534 and smaller than -840 i.e. I thought there is better way to do this than the 'if' construction.

Comment: looking at your solution below I think that you didn't specify your question enough. If you have specified what behavior is expected when number is out of bounds, you'd get different answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (variable < -840 || variable > 534)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException(variable + " is out of range");
```

If you want to be able to turn this off at runtime, take a look at the `assert` keyword.

Comment: Yeah .. I meant without a if construction.. wouldn't the Math.max/min static method be 'cheaper' ?

Comment: No. You cannot get cheaper than this. Math.max would do at the least the same work, most likely more, plus there is method calling overhead -- the latter should not stop you from making your own `assertInRange(int,int,int)` method if you need this check a lot, though.

Comment: +1 `IllegalArgumentException` is the way to go, but make sure that the acceptable range is clearly specified if for example the variable has a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very clear what you are asking but if it's a general scenario like a class variable, best and easiest way is to encapsulate your variable, and in the setter method check the variable and throw an exception if it's out of the range.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.max` will a little bit more expensive, but more importantly will not very very straightforward to the *reader*.

`if(number > MIN && number < MAX)` is the most straightforward, and the best way of checking this.

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers helped me, so here is what I found (in case someone else is looking for the same):

Rather than throwing an error, this solution accepts input above and below the limits and simply outputs the clipped value.

`Math.max` and `Math.min` can be helpful for doing this:

```
Math.max(Math.min(input, MAX), MIN)
```

Here are the three basic cases; one integer within the limit, one above, and one below:

```
static final int MIN= -840;
static final int MAX = 534;

int inputX = -892; // less than minNumber
int inputY = 290; // within range
int inputZ = 1234; // greater than maxNumber

System.out.println( Math.max(Math.min(inputX, MAX), MIN) ); // -840
System.out.println( Math.max(Math.min(inputY, MAX), MIN) ); // 290
System.out.println( Math.max(Math.min(inputZ, MAX), MIN) ); // 534
```

This graph shows how the input (x) and output (y) are related.

[image: input/output graph]

Comment: This is not the most performant solution, checking bounds in a if is faster

Comment: The source for `Math.min(long a, long b)` is `return (a <= b) ? a : b;` and max is similar. Doesn't get faster than that.

Comment: Yes, but you always do it twice (also a Math.min).

Comment: You have a valid point, but only for really extreme cases. Even with javascript it is going to take less than a millisecond to do a million of these double Math evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

define two constants one for MIN one for MAX, and check always that your variable is inside them

Answer (score 0):

Old question. I'll leave it in case anyone else needs it

I solved it with the annotations

```
@Max(value = 534)
@Min(value = -840)
private Short digits;
```